# Given the inhomogeneous linear differential equation, $dx/dt + x = 2t$, use the given ansatz to find a solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Like the image shows, I'm given an  inhomogeneous differential equation and an initial condition, but the task is to find the general solution to an homogenous equation. What is that supposed to mean? Do I just substitute the 1 with a 0 randomly and proceed like that? What about the initial condition I was given. If there was no text the obvious thing would be to simply find a general solution of the ODE and the related special solution with the given i.c, but I'm instead asked to find 3 different equations that I can't see fitting in the problem. Help please?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdz4e.png

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: This is the most simple case of the general method of variation of constants. // How would you solve this equation (when not directly using the full solution formula)? Chances are that you do exactly what the task demands, without giving it this specific structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are fairly clear as to what is expected and how the process of finding a solution works. In this case given an equation of the type
$$ \frac{d \, x}{dt} + a \, x = p(t) \hspace{10mm} x(0) = 0 $$
then first find the solution of $$ \frac{d \, x}{dt} + a \, x = 0 $$ which happens to be $ x(t) = e^{-a \, t}$. Now the method is to find the complete solution of the original equation with a solution of the form $$ x(t) = f(t) \, e^{- a t}. $$ This leads to
\begin{align}
\frac{d x}{dt} + x &= p(t) \\
-a \, f \, e^{-a t} + \frac{d f}{dt} \, e^{-a t} + f \, e^{-a t} &= p \\
\frac{d f}{dt} + (1-a) \, f &= p \, e^{a t} \\
f(t) &= e^{(a-1) \, t} \, \left( c_{0} + \int^{t} e^{u} \, p(u) \, du \right).
\end{align}
Using $x(0) = f(0) = 0$ gives
$$ f(t) = e^{(a-1) t} \, \int_{0}^{t} e^{u} \, p(u) \, du. $$
The final solution
$$ x(t) = e^{- a t} \, \int_{0}^{t} e^{u} \, p(u) \, du. $$

From here it is a matter of equating $a$ and $p(t)$ to obtain the specific solution to the problem.